# Taking screenshot no matter what scale the resolution is

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I'm taking a screenshot of the WorkingArea of my PrimaryScreen. If the resolution is set to 100% in Windows, it works perfectly fine[image: Screenshot with 100%]

But if the resolution is set to 150%, it takes a partial screenshot.[image: Screenshot with 150%]

The code I've made goes like this:

```
Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(captureBitmap);
captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(captureRectangle.Left, captureRectangle.Top, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size);
captureBitmap.Save($@"{_localDestination}\{timeStampFormated}\Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

What am I missing, in order to have it take a screenshot and doesn't care about scaling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try replace size in `new Bitmap`, with size of `captureRectangle`? you need exchange 1st and 2nd statement.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean it like this? Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(captureRectangle.Width, captureRectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Comment: yes. i'm just suggest a try, not sure work or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same thing happens.

Comment: [Taking a screenshot using Graphics.CopyFromScreen with 150% scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438736/taking-a-screenshot-using-graphics-copyfromscreen-with-150-scaling)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows screenshot with scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015893/windows-screenshot-with-scaling) Just checked -  setting dpiAware in manifest to true/pm fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN Yes, that did the trick! Thank you :)